# Do "Query" and "Quarry" have smiilar etymological roots?

Tags: etymology

To "Query" is the primary method to extract information from a database.  A "quarry" is the place where minerals are extracted from the ground.  I'm curious if these share similar etymology as they both have very similar sounds and very similar uses?

Thanks.

Comment: @StoneyB I didn't see your comment before I posted.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 There's no need to apologize for doing the actual work I skipped. :)

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

I will refer you to the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com).

**query** from Latin quaere "ask,". Spelling altered c. 1600 by influence of inquiry.

**quarry** from Medieval Latin quareia, dissimilated from quarreria (mid-13c.), literally "place where stones are squared," from Latin quadrare "to make square,".

Answer (score 3):

No there is no etymological link between the two terms despite their assonance. They both come from Latin:

[query](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=query&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.) :

> - ***1530s, quaere "a question," from Latin quaere "ask," imperative of quaerere "to seek, look for;*** strive, endeavor, strive to gain; ask, require, demand;" figuratively "seek mentally, seek to learn, make inquiry," probably ultimately from PIE root *kwo-, stem of relative and interrogative pronouns. ***Spelling Englished or altered c. 1600 by influence of inquiry.***

[quarry](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=quarry&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.2) :

> - ***Borrowing from Medieval Latin quarreria (1266), literally a "place where stones are squared"***, from Old French quarrière (compare modern French carrière), from Vulgar Latin *quadraria, from Latin quadrō (“I square”) itself from quadra (“a square”).
> - "open place where rocks are excavated," c. 1400 (mid-13c. as a place name), from Medieval Latin quareia, dissimilated from quarreria (mid-13c.), ***literally "place where stones are squared," from Latin quadrare "to make square," related to quadrus "a square," quattuor "four"***

(Etymonline)